# How to copy a file into Linux back from the server (30ngs) using scp command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scp

how to copy a file into Linux back from the server (30ngs). I am using scp command.
The command i used to copy a file from Ubuntu to Server is as follows. And it work well.

```
tahir@D3C1209-VIRTUAL:~$ scp bvd1.fa usman@30ngs:/home/usman/training/
```

My query is how to copy the file `bvd1.fa` back to ubuntu from the server?
I am using the command:

```
tahir@D3C1209-VIRTUAL:~$ scp -r bvd1.fa usman@30ngs:/home/usman/training/
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should do `scp usman@30ngs:/home/usman/training/bvd1.fa .`

---

More generally, `scp` is like `cp`. Its first parameter is the source and the second parameter is the target. You can do either

```
scp local/path/to/file user@hostname:remote/path
```

or

```
scp user@hostname:remote/path/to/file local/path
```

By the way, the `-r` option does not stand for "reversed", it is "recursive".

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Yeah, it works. Thanks for solving my puzzle.

Comment: @Dr.TahirUsman Then please accept my answer as the solution. (There should be a button under the volt-up/down buttons, on the left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

The `scp` syntax is `scp <source> <destination>` and in this case the remote server is your source and the local directory is the destination. Thus, you need to use the following command:

```
$ scp usman@30ngs:/home/usman/training/bvd1.fa .
```

Comment: Dear friend, Thanks for your prompt reponse. Your guidence proved helpful for me. Best regards